# OpenERP 6.1 - wizard should not close on button click

Tags: button, popup, odoo, popupwindow

Hi i added a button on my wizard form to open another wizard but i don't want to close existing one, the reason for an another wizard is just to pass some value after user filter and choose few data.

on my wizard form i added a button with below code

```
>   def action_process_pickings(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
>         if context is None: context = {}
>         context = dict(context, active_ids=ids, active_model=self._name)
>         
>         return {
>             'name':_("Picking to Process"),
>             'view_mode': 'form',
>             'view_id': False,
>             'view_type': 'form',
>             'res_model': 'packing.wizard',
>             'res_id': ids[0],
>             'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
>             'nodestroy': True,
>             'target': 'new',
>             'domain': '[]',
>             'context': context,
>         }
```

I believe the solution is to put in "nodestroy" equal to True, it works on OpenERP 6.0 & 7.0 but not on 6.1, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Going from memory here but if you have the button method return None rather than a window action if will log a warning but leave the window in place.  Pretty sure this works in 6.1

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question,
Rather than make existing windows stay open, better return as windows action to 1st windows from the 2nd popup windows. This is the best way i can find in 6.1

For example :

- I have a osv memory popup with model A
- I added a button to open another osv memory popup windows with model B
- Then on model B i will return something to model A

The code for button on model A shld be :

> def buttonA(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
>           if context is None: context = {}
>           context = dict(context, active_ids=ids, active_model=self._name)
>
> ```
>     return {
>         'name':_("Picking to Process"),
>         'view_mode': 'form',
>         'view_id': False,
>         'view_type': 'form',
>         'res_model': 'b',
>         'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
>         'nodestroy': True,
>         'target': 'new',
>         'domain': '[]',
>         'context': context,
>     }
> ```

Then the code for button on model B is simply to update data A which what it supposed to be, and return to model A with windows action

```
   def buttonB(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
         if context is None: context = {}         
         self.pool.get('a').write(cr, uid, { [the value u want to update] })
         return {
             'name':_("Picking to Process"),
             'view_mode': 'form',
             'view_id': False,
             'view_type': 'form',
             'res_model': 'a,
             'res_id': context.get('active_ids')[0],
             'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
             'nodestroy': True,
             'target': 'new',
             'domain': '[]',
             'context': context,
         }
```